# Integration Stripe Angular, Cannot find name 'Stripe'. Did you mean 'stripe'?

Tags: angular, typescript, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe with redirection to my app, I am using Angular-typescript.

Here is the code I have so far in my component:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function() {
  console.log('Script loaded');
  var stripe = Stripe(MY_PUBLICK_KEY);
  return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: SESSION_I_RETURNED_FROM_MY_BACKEND});
}
script.src = 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/';
head.appendChild(script);
```

But I have the following error running the above code:

`Cannot find name 'Stripe'. Did you mean 'stripe'?`

I have installed package with the command `npm install --save stripe` following the next guide https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder

Is there anyone that faced the same problem when integrating Stripe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `stripe` package corresponds to `stripe-node`, [a server-side library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#stripe-nodejs-library). For a client-side Angular application, you need [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js).

Stripe has a module loader helper library available: `@stripe/stripe-js` ([link](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js#installation))
You might also want to look at the community made `ngx-stripe` library, but if you are primarily using `redirectToCheckout` you can likely skip this.